# CGPA Calculation for US institutions

Tags: graduate-admissions, engineering, electrical-engineering

A US university's application portal has provided this 4-point scale and told me to note the CGPA.
Where A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, E/F=0

How do I convert my CGPA to this scale? MY undergrad CGPA scale has A+=4(80-100), A=3.75(75-79), A-=3.5(70-74), B+=3.25 and similar grades. The program page where the converted CGPA should be mentioned also leads to WES country resource page where 60-100 is A, 50-59 is B and so on. This is all a bit too confusing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The first an second system seems to be quasi identical, just with different resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It is typical in the US to let the institution you apply to to do the calculation based on official numbers from your own institution and knowledge of the country.

If you are asked to do a conversion, it is fine to just say something like 3.8/4.0 if that would be the official GPA.

But note that in US institutions 70-74 might actually be a C or C+ grade, so it is very difficult to do a fair and honest computation. But institutions are good about knowing the vagaries of grading systems around the world. And the reason that 70 might be A- in one place and C in another is just the way that the educators in different places typically grade the student's work, including, perhaps, the difficult of the tasks graded. There is no universal standard. And not all institutions in the US even have A+ grades and when they do is probably more like 97/100 and above.

You are normally required, in the US, to provide transcripts as well, so that individual grades can be seen and the institution applied to has knowledge of where the grades were given and probably understand what is typical there.

So, don't overthink it. A simple statement that conforms to your degree granting institution is what  is expected. In particular, don't try to make it look better than it is.

---

Something that is harder to recognize is that if your own professors judge you on whatever basis to be an excellent student (A level) then that is very likely to be accepted elsewhere. That matters more, I think, than the numbers themselves. And, in the US you will be asked for letters of recommendation that are considered very important. More so than some other places. This reinforces the sense given by the numeric scores, however they translate.

Comment: Thank you very much